# Is it acceptable to wait until the grace period to award a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounties, etiquette

I've posted a bounty on a question, and someone's posted a good answer in response. Is it socially acceptable to wait until the grace period starts, to see if someone posts an even better answer?

Comment: I wait until grace period at probably 99% of [200+ bounties I offered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=bounties&sort=offered). Bounty => exposure => good answer can get more votes up while exposed => the longer it's exposed, the more chances for others to see and reward it

Comment: ...think of it as changing bounty type to _reward existing answer_ on the fly

Comment: I wish there was a way to mark an answer as the 'current' best answer so that, if no better answer comes along, that answer gets auto-awarded the bounty once time is up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. Or at least, it had better be, since this is what I always do.

The bounty should be awarded to the most deserving eligible answer, right? How will you know which one that is if you don't wait until the grace period starts?

Comment: Definitely that. Just don't forget to actually award it in the end :)